# Best way to pass single value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that posts a single value, but I cant seem to get it to the controller.  I have verified the value exists in the form, but it arrives at the controller as null.  Here is the form post:

```
            <%Html.BeginForm("SaveRecord", "NewApplicant", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.PersonModel.ApplicantID } ); %>
                <%: Html.Hidden("NewId", Model.PersonModel.ApplicantID) %>
                <input type="submit" class="SKButton" value="Save" title="Save this new application as a unique record." />
            <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

and here is the contoller action:

```
    public ActionResult SaveRecord(NewApplicantViewModel model)
    {

        int NewAppId = model.PersonModel.ApplicantID;
```

I have also tried:

```
    public ActionResult SaveRecord(int NewId)
    {

        model.PersonModel.ApplicantID = NewId;
```

These must be a simple fix, and I want to pass the id in the model, dont want to use ajax.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonModel.ApplicantID) %>
```